# Can't read my SMS on my Android phone

Tags: sms, 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4

> An update fixed my problem. It was - as I suspected - just a bug.

Recently I upgrade my Samsung s4, and now every time when I get a message via SMS, the text - and background - all white?:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>
[image: IMG: sample]

I tried messing with the settings, but still my messages won't show up?

How can I read my SMS messages again?

Phone Info

- Samsung S4(`GT-I9505`)
- Android version 5.0.1.

Comment: Backup your data and then restore factory settings may help. Also install any other launcher may help

Comment: If you don't want to do that, switch to another messaging app, like Hangouts?  Atleast then you can get your messages while you figure out what the problem is with the Messaging app... (also, have you tried closing and clearing the cache of Messaging, not sure if that will help though)

Comment: @Mike how do I clear the cache of messagin?

Answer (score 0):

Try a third party messaging app, such as Google Messenger or Handcent SMS to see if the problem is duplicated. If so, verify you're running the most current software version with Samsung Kies. If you are, try a factory reset and see if that works. There's a possibility that the Lollipop update for the S4 has some bugs that will hopefully be patched rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I used Hangouts to get around this problem, however last night my phone downloaded a software update that has corrected the Messages app, updated Contacts with FB photos and re-linked my phone to the FB photo albums - hoorah! Oh how I've missed Swype when sending out text messages :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can't read SMS in Lollipop without approved permission in run time. First, check permission in run time, then you can access SMS.

Answer (score 0):

My default *Messages* app suddenly stopped opening texts. (could write them though and only had about 50 txt messages in total). Oppo phone android software didn't give 'clear cache' option for Messages. However, found an app on my phone called *Messenger*. Once this was disabled, *Messages* app worked again (no reboot necessary)

Answer (score 0):

As per [the OP's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105404/cant-read-my-sms-on-my-android-phone#comment165695_105404) and [the 4th revision of the question](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/105404/4)

> Apparently, the answer to this, is Update your Samsung device
>
> An update fixed my problem. It was - as I suspected - just a bug.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured it out.. I turned off my phone for 20 seconds and my phone messages showed up.  If you keep your phone on all the time like I do,  then turn it off and back on, your messages should return.

Answer (score -2):

Phone could be in Guest Mode.  Go to settings...security...then deactivate guest mode.

Comment: That wasn't it. The questioner already updated their question to say it was fixed by a software update.